# How to write Command for StackLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In my project i have used the `XamEffects` packages Reference
[enter link description here](https://github.com/mrxten/XamEffects/blob/master/README.md)

```
<StackLayout effect:Commands.Tap="{Binding OnTapped}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" effect:TouchEffect.Color="Gray" effect:EffectsConfig.ChildrenInputTransparent="True">
    <Image Source="ic_cont_downtick.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" WidthRequest="250" Spacing="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Downloaded Content" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black"/>
            <Label BackgroundColor="#455EEC" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="4"/>
        </StackLayout>
    <Image Source="ic_rightarrow_1.png" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
</StackLayout>
```

while clicking the stackLayout have to Navigate another Page. But `TapGestureRecognizer` won't work with this package. Only Command will work.

So please help me out.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code for binding in ViewModel class

```
private Command onTapped;
private const string OnTappedCommandPropertyName = "OnTapped";

public Command OnTapped
{
    get
    {
        return onTapped ?? (onTapped = new Command(ExecuteOnTappedCommand));
    }
}

public void ExecuteOnTappedCommand()
{
    //your code here
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @ Ramya Its not Working

Comment: @nandha I worked on a sample project https://github.com/ramyareddyn/Sample and it is working

Comment: I will take a look on it.Thanks@Ramya

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need of any package in xamarin forms to do so, All you need to do is

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding tryit}"/>

    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label Text="hello touch me"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I need a touch effect so i have used this package

Comment: are you using xamarin prism?

Answer (score 1):

I specified in Readme, you cannot use gestures with my effect:

> Important: if you need some gestures with touch effect, use not
>   GestureRecognizer, but Commands because effects doesn't work correctly
>   with standard gestures in Xamarin.Forms.

Please use [commands](https://github.com/mrxten/XamEffects#commands) in your control for that:

```
effect:TouchEffect.Color="Gray" 
effect:Commands.Tap="{Binding TapCommand}"
effect:EffectsConfig.ChildrenInputTransparent="True"
```

In ViewModel create ICommand:

```cs
private ICommand _tapCommand;
public ICommand TapCommand => _tapCommand ?? (_tapCommand = new Command(TapExecute));

private void TapExecute()
{
   //something
}
```